# Internet Explorer is not closing via selenium script with every solution

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

I am Not able to close the Internet Explorer via selenium script, I tried every Solution to Kill the IEDriver task and Iexplorer.exe.

I also Tried solution:  **Internet Explorer 11 does not close after Selenium Test 2**  but it still not working for me.
I am Using below,
Selenium 3.4, 
IE: 11.1358.14393.0, 
InternetExplorerServerDriver: 3.4.0

Below is my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Tc03_IEDriver_First_use {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Set IEDriver Properties
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Rohit Bhatkar\\Selenium Jars\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        //Set desired Capabilities of IE. these statements removes an zoomsetting error.
        //You Can set Zoom mannually as, Go To View Menu on IE > Click On Zoom > Select 100% 
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        //Create IEDriver obj, Open Browser, Open URL, Close the Browser
        WebDriver obj1= new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
        obj1.manage().window().maximize();
        obj1.get("https://www.google.com");
        obj1.quit(); //IE not Closing. Steel need to do some work to close the browser

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to first `obj1.close()` to close the browser window. Then I would use `obj1.quit()` to quit the webdriver which would close it's terminal window in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine. I tested it and the IE browser closed at the end.

Try `obj1.close();` instead of `obj1.quit();`

Comment: Hello,
I tried to Do that Also, its not working with obj1.close()

Comment: Thanks For Answering the Question.
I Tried it before. Script doesn't show any error on console.

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.4.0.0
Listening on port 14419
Only local connections are allowed
Jul 25, 2017 3:27:15 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Comment: Hello,
I Found the Issue, If I try  to close the browser without opening any URL, it closes the browser, but, as soon as the browser title changed it looks for the title 'WebDriver' to close the window. and i am not able to find the same. If any one have solution to this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Try these settings for IE 11:

> `Note`: You have to set **`Zoom Level`** to **100%** for IE to work properly.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability("platform", "WIN8"); 
cap.setCapability("version", "11"); 
cap.setCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",1);
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents","false");
cap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
cap.setCapability("requireWindowFocus","true");
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://google.co.in");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your Answer.
It Still Not working on my System.
I found one thing that, it is looking for the browser which has 'WebDriver' as title to close. But after opening URL the title has been changed to 'Google'. I think thats why selenium is not closing the browser window.
below is the console text,

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.4.0.0
Listening on port 3225
Only local connections are allowed
Jul 25, 2017 4:34:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
WebDriver

Comment: Did my Answer help you out? Thanks

Comment: Hello,
I Found the Issue, If I try  to close the browser without opening any URL, it closes the browser, but, as soon as the browser title changed it looks for the title 'WebDriver' to close the window. and i am not able to find the same. If any one have solution to this please let me know.